# What unit is used to display Redis CPU usage

Tags: linux, redis

I ran the command `INFO CPU` in the Redis CLI and got the output shown below:

```
used_cpu_sys:4785.73
used_cpu_user:4843.73
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00
```

My question is: what is the unit used for these figures?

Is it CPU time, or CPU consumption or something else?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is the CPU time (expressed in seconds) accumulated since the launch of the Redis instance, as reported by the [getrusage()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) call.