# Calculate % Processor Utilization in Redis

Tags: redis

Using [`INFO CPU`](https://redis.io/commands/info) command on Redis, I get the following values back (among other values):

> used_cpu_sys:688.80
>
> used_cpu_user:622.75

Based on my understanding, the value indicates the CPU time (expressed in seconds) accumulated since the launch of the Redis instance, as reported by the getrusage() call ([`source`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680032/what-unit-is-used-to-display-redis-cpu-usage)).

What I need to do is calculate the % CPU utilization based on these values. I looked extensively for an approach to do so but unfortunately couldn't find a way.

So my questions are:

1. Can we actually calculate the % CPU utilization based on these 2 values? If the answer is yes, then I would appreciate some pointers in that direction.
2. Do we need some extra data points for this calculation? If the answer is yes, I would appreciate if someone can tell me what those data points would be.

P.S. If this question should belong to Server Fault, please let me know and I will post it there (I wasn't 100% sure if it belongs here or there).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read the value twice, calculate the delta, and divide by the time elapsed between the two reads. That should give you the cpu usage in % for that duration.

Comment: Thanks Kirk! I have one more question: So in my case I am issuing this command from a remote machine. How would I account for network latency? So I issue this command at some time and I get the data back a few milliseconds later. Then after I issue 2nd command say 10 seconds after and then get data back a few milliseconds after that. How would I account for the time spent in sending the request and receiving the response? Or should I just treat this as a "margin or error"? Any input regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not in a place where I can test it, but I am wondering if you used the command MULTI and did the INFO CPU and TIME commands with multi each time. Then you'd get the cpu info and the exact time on the server within microseconds of each command. Then compute from there. This way, you could in theory avoid the network latency entirely. My only hesitation is MULTI is normally combined with EXEC which is primarily for work on objects as I recall, but it might work.

Comment: Thank you. Let me give it a try.