# How can I judge cpu load from Redis "INFO CPU"

Tags: redis

I know `INFO CPU` call [getrusage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) to get cpu resource usage.
    but the number accumulated since the launch of the Redis instance,see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680032/what-unit-is-used-to-display-redis-cpu-usage).
    so, I think even if this number is large （eg, used_cpu_user:203.56）,but it does not reflect the current cpu load.
    I wonder what information should I get from it? or how can i judge cpu load from the command?
    Thank you very much.